# Failed to sign Firefox WebExtensions with web-ext

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm porting a Chrome extension to Firefox WebExtensions. Everything works fine on Chrome.

I've tried these on Firefox:

**1.** Modify my extension to make it compatible with Firefox WebExtensions, then load it in Firefox by `Load Temporary Add-on`, everything works fine

**2.** Install `web-ext` module by `npm install -g web-ext`. Then I run `web-ext run`, Firefox started successfully with my extension installed

**3.** Run `web-ext build`, then install the packaged extension on Firefox, all worked fine

```
D:\temp>web-ext build
Building web extension from D:\temp
Your web extension is ready: D:\temp\web-ext-artifacts\my_extension-1.0.zip
```

**4.** Then I run `web-ext sign --api-key=MyApiKey --api-secret=MyApiSecret`, it failed with error:

```
D:\temp>web-ext sign --api-key=MyApiKey --api-secret=MyApiSecret
Building web extension from D:\temp

sign: Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-web-ext-628J9dJMBi0bWRX'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.rmdirSync (fs.js:806:18)
    at _rmdirRecursiveSync (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web-ext\node_modules\tmp\lib\tmp.js:284:10)
    at TempDir._cleanupCallback [as _removeTempDir] (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web-ext\node_modules\tmp\lib\tmp.js:408:5)
    at TempDir.remove (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web-ext\dist\webpack:\src\util\temp-dir.js:9:4939)
    at C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web-ext\dist\webpack:\src\util\temp-dir.js:9:3976
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:401:9)

sign: Error code: ENOTEMPTY
```

I went into `C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-web-ext-628J9dJMBi0bWRX` and in fact it is empty. Does anybody know why this happens?

My api key and api secret are for old Firefox JSCTypes add-ons. Is this the reason why I keep getting this error?

Here is [document of web-ext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution to this problem**

After some more digging, I found the reason that caused this error, is that I'm using proxy on my network. I try to set proxy by running command `set HTTP_PROXY=MyProxyServerAddress`, then the error disappears.

**Other trouble shooting**

Then I tried to run `web-ext sign` again, and found another error:

```
Server response: You do not own this addon. (status: 403)
sign: WebExtError: The WebExtension could not be signed
```

I upload my add-on(packaged generated by `web-ext build`) to [Mozilla Add-on Site](https://addons.mozilla.org/), then run `web-ext sign` again. This time add-on was signed successfully.

> **Note:** You need to change your add-on's version each time running `web-ext sign`. Otherwise it will fail with error: `Server response: Version already exists. (status: 409)`

**Cheers!**