# Firefox web-ext run failing after running profile

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, web-ext

I am trying my hand at building a simple extension for Firefox, but got the following error when running `web-ext run`:

```
Error: not found: firefox
    at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/node_modules/fx-runner/node_modules/which/which.js:63:19)
    at E (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/node_modules/fx-runner/node_modules/which/which.js:72:29)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/node_modules/fx-runner/node_modules/which/which.js:81:16
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/node_modules/fx-runner/node_modules/isexe/index.js:44:5
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/node_modules/fx-runner/node_modules/isexe/access.js:8:5
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:23)
```

NOTE: I am running this in Ubuntu Linux subsystem for Windows 10. Not sure if that affects anything, but that's why the directory structures are a bit weird. I've also tried running the same commands on Firefox Developer Edition with the same results.

I tried the following commands:

```
web-ext run -v
web-ext run -v --firefox="C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

These give the following response:

```
[/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/lib/program.js][info] Version: 7.6.2
[/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/lib/program.js][debug] Discovering config files. Set --no-config-discovery to disable
[/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/lib/config.js][debug] Discovered config "/home/knuffle98/.web-ext-config.js" does not exist or is not readable
[/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/lib/config.js][debug] Discovered config "/mnt/c/Users/Knuffle98/Code/Repos/Applicator/package.json" does not exist or is not readable
[/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/lib/config.js][debug] Discovered config "/mnt/c/Users/Knuffle98/Code/Repos/Applicator/web-ext-config.js" does not exist or is not readable
[/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/lib/cmd/run.js][info] Running web extension from /mnt/c/Users/Knuffle98/Code/Repos/Applicator
[/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/lib/util/manifest.js][debug] Validating manifest at /mnt/c/Users/Knuffle98/Code/Repos/Applicator/manifest.json
[/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/lib/extension-runners/firefox-desktop.js][debug] Creating new Firefox profile
[/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/lib/firefox/index.js][debug] Running Firefox with profile at /tmp/firefox-profilesTWUXQ/
[/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/lib/program.js][error]
Error: not found: C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
    at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/node_modules/fx-runner/node_modules/which/which.js:63:19)
    at E (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/node_modules/fx-runner/node_modules/which/which.js:72:29)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/node_modules/fx-runner/node_modules/which/which.js:81:16
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/node_modules/fx-runner/node_modules/isexe/index.js:44:5
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/node_modules/fx-runner/node_modules/isexe/access.js:8:5
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:23)
```

What do you guys think is the problem?

For reference, it's a couple steps before this problem:
[Failed to sign Firefox WebExtensions with web-ext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693257/failed-to-sign-firefox-webextensions-with-web-ext)

Comment: Since it's a linux subsystem it needs your firefox to be a linux app not a windows app. I don't know how to launch windows apps from WSL but if there's no way just don't use WSL as you don't need it for web-ext.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue with `web-ext` on WSL for Firefox. Interestingly, specifying the target as chromium works for me: `web-ext run --target=chromium`. It's unclear why for Chrome it doesn't throw an error as both are installed as windows executables.

But assuming you are using WSL for development only, consider  developing and/or building your extension on WSL and then for testing, run `web-ext` from your source folder on Windows using the command prompt. This is a just a workaround, but it worked for me and I was able launch Firefox with the extension loaded.

Alternatively, you can try to install Firefox on WSL. There is an existing AskUbuntu question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1444962/how-do-i-install-firefox-in-wsl-when-it-requires-snap-but-snap-doesnt-work) that you can refer. The following is borrowed from the accepted answer.

Refer to this url for installation guide: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/install-firefox-deb-ubuntu-22-04/. First two steps are optional for package removal:

```
    sudo snap remove firefox
    sudo apt remove firefox
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
    
    # Create a new file, it should be empty as it opens:
    sudo gedit /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozillateamppa
    
    # Insert these lines, then save and exit
    Package: firefox*
    Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
    Pin-Priority: 501
    
    # after saving, do
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install firefox # or firefox-esr
```